# How to run a node from swift

Tags: swift, macos, forever

I am trying to stop a `nodejs` server started using forever using below command:

```
func shell(command: String) -> Int32 {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = ["sh", "-c", command]
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        return task.terminationStatus
    }

shell(command: "$forever_PATH/forever stop node.js")
```

I am seeing below error:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
PS:node is located in /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: seems to be envoirnment variable not set, you can try by giving hard code path o of your node

Comment: `launchPath` is deprecated in 10.13. Try to use `task.currentDirectoryURL` and `task.executableURL`. For more information https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  func shell(path:String,commandargs: [String]) -> Bool
    {
        let task = Process()
        var ret : Bool = false

      task.launchPath = path
      task.arguments = commandargs
      task.launch()
      task.waitUntilExit()
        if !task.isRunning {
            let status = task.terminationStatus
            if status == 0 {
                ret = true
            } else {
                ret = false
            }
        }
         return ret

    }
```

Call it as below

```
shell(path: "/usr/local/bin/node", commandargs: ["PathToforever","stop","nodejsscript.js"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a sandbox issue. Go into your app’s entitlement page and delete the sandbox section.

That fixed my issue with files not being found.

Caveat is that you will not be able to post app to App Store.